# List of functions $f(cx) = C\cdot f(x)$

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, special-functions

I was looking for some complex functions f(x), which satisfies the condition:

$$\exists (c, C) \in \Bbb C^2 \backslash\{(1,1)\}, \forall x \in \Bbb C, f(cx) = C\cdot f(x)$$

Till now I have got

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{Function, $f(x)$}&\text{Remarks}\\
x^d&\text{d is some constant}\\
\log(d^x)&\text{d is some constant}\\
sin(x\pi)&-\\
cos(x\pi)&-\\
tan(x\pi)&-\\
|x|&-
\end{array}$$

which satisfies this condition.

But I am looking for more complex functions which satisfies the same condition.

Comment: Do $\sin \cos$ and $\tan$ work?

Comment: I think what he mean is that for all $x$, there's a $c$ and $C$ such that $f(cx)=Cf(x)$ for $\sin$ it is $\sin(-x)=-\sin{x}$. But this kind of function are numerous. We take take arbitrary even or odd function, or other function like homogeneous ones.

Comment: What are the conditions on $x$, $c$ and $C$? Do you also want the function $f$ to be continuous? As I read it right now every non-zero function satisfies you property, because you can always scale the function with $C$.

Comment: If $c=C$ then you can compose and two functions with that property. $f (g (cx))=f (c\cdot g (x))=c\cdot f (g (x))$. You can add and subtract them too and have arbitrary constants multiplying them

Comment: All even and odd functions satisfy your condition. A hopefully useful remark is that the range of $f(cx)$ is the same as the range of $f$, but the range of $Cf(x)$ is obtained from the range of $f$ by a stretching/shrinking. Similar properties for the domains of the two functions.

Comment: @Golbez I have edited the contition accordingly, since it's complete nonsense otherwise. However, since the OP is writing about complex functions, there may be a problem with the log, and with non-integer powers.

Comment: What about $c=C=1$...?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Good observation, I edited the question.

Comment: $\log(d^x)=x\log(d)$, and this is the same as $x^d$ with $d=1$. More generally, $x^d$ and $|x|^d$ work. But I don't see what you mean with the trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 1):

**If C and c are constant:**
$$cf'(cx)=Cf'(x)$$
$$f'(cx)=\frac Ccf'(x)=\frac{C^2}{c^2}f'(\frac xc)=\cdots=\frac{C^n}{c^n}|_{n\to\infty}f'(0)$$

- If $c>1$:
  $$f(cx)=\frac{C^n}{c^n}|_{n\to\infty}f'(0)x+C$$
  $$f(x)=\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac Cc\right)^n\right]f'(0)\frac xc+\mathcal{Constant}$$

  - If $C>c$:
  - If $f'(0)=0$ , $f(x)=\mathcal{Constant}$
  - If $f'(0)\ne0$ , $f(x)\to\infty$
  - If $C<c$, $f(x)=\mathcal{Constant}$
  - If $C=c$, $\displaystyle f(x)=\left(\frac{f'(0)}c\right)x+\mathcal{Constant}$
- If $c=\pm1$

  - **If $c=1$**, $$f'(x)={C^n}|_{n\to\infty}f'(0)\implies f(x)={C^n}|_{n\to\infty}f'(0)x+\mathcal{Constant}$$
  - Some similiar results to previous one if $C>1,C=1,C<1$, Think yourself.
  - If $C=\pm1$, All even and odd functions.
- If $c<1$

  - Some similiar cases, Think yourself.

**If C and c are variable:**
Every function satisfies the required condition.